# how to remove filename from URL?

Tags: php

I have a path like following

```
http://localhost/streamcola/watch/getvideo.php
```

I want to remove /getvideo.php and just want the following path

```
http://localhost/streamcola/watch
```

how can i do this.?
I not rewriting my URL , i just want to remove extension only.

Comment: why are you doing this?

Comment: You should look at apache [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/fr/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: You can use DirectoryIndex https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/fr/mod/mod_dir.html

Comment: you can use `.htaccess`  something http://www.htaccess-guide.com/

Comment: I also want to do it, in URL when on Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File name removal is complex but its possible, but i do this by removing the extension of the file, 
As my Filename is getvideo.php and i want http://localhost/streamcola/watch
So i change my file name to watch.php and remove that .php extension
This is done by creating a new file named .htaccess file. I place it with my watch.php file and code of that .htyaccess file is following

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

and hence i get my desired URL..

Answer (score 0):

The effect you want to achieve is called url-rewriting.
This is ususally something your server does via configuration and thus differs depending on your server (e.g. apache2, nginx, tomcat etc.)
Please refer this Article as a startingpoint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine

Comment: Reading that article, it looks, fine,

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply "mod_rewrite" for your URLs. It cannot be done without modifying .htaccess file, or just rename getvideo.php to index.php when opening http://localhost/streamcola/watch it will redirect to index.php.

Comment: I did this , but it shows index.php also

Comment: It will show if you write http://localhost/streamcola/watch/index.php , but it won't if you write http://localhost/streamcola/watch into your adress bar.

Comment: lol @EasternEuropean, the point is justly that op is not writing the url they wish in the url bar. you're basically saying, hey, why don't you write the correct url in the first place?

Comment: Brother, thats wwhat i want, I want that file working, but not want to see its name in URL

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
<?php
$subject = <your String>;
$pattern = '/(.*)\/.*\.php?/';
preg_match($pattern, substr($subject,3), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Edit: 
Sorry, i thought you had a string you want to modify.

Comment: It didn't works, it shows the file name in body, i want it in URL

Comment: please specify your question as i don't really know what you want to achieve.

Comment: I just want to achieve a URL that doesnot contain my filename,

Comment: Maybe have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained

Comment: looking ..........